# Fine tuning a dotplot in R's lattice package

Tags: r

I am probably breaking multiple rules by posting this question here, but I really want to find the answer to this question and after looking for several hours, I don't seem be getting anywhere. I already posted the question on StackOverflow and I didn't get any response (my guess is that 90% of R users are here and 80% of them don't follow StackOverflow).  I will repeat the question here as well, so that you don't have to login there to respond. I will greatly appreciate any help.

I am trying to plot a bunch of ROC areas for different datasets and different algorithms. I have three variables: "Scheme" which specifies the algorithm used, "Dataset" is the dataseet that the algorithm is being tested on, and "Area_under_ROC".

I am using the lattice library in R, with the following command:

```
dotplot(Scheme ~ Area_under_ROC | Dataset, data = simulationSummary, layout = c(4,6))
```

and this is what I get:

[dotplot of Scheme vs. Area_under_ROC, conditioned on Dataset](http://s18.postimage.org/ebuj2ddjt/dotplot.jpg)

What I'd like to know is

- How can make the labels on the y-axis readable? Right now, they're all squeezed together.
- How can I re-arrange the panel in such a way that the datasets marked with "100" form the last column rather than the second column, but the other columns stay the same?

I'd very much appreciate any comments or pointers. Many Thanks!

Comment: Please don't cross-post, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9695704/604456. And if the answer on SO doesn't meet your needs it is best to elaborate there than it is to ask the exact same question again here.

Comment: I've answered your question on SO (and suggested some possible dataviz improvements). Don't cross post in the future, please, especially when this is purely a language-related issue. If, on the contrary, you seek advice about the best way to display a summary of your data then your question will be welcome here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your font smaller so the labels don't overlap, try `scales=list (cex=0.5)` in your call. The column order depends on the order of your factors in Dataset. Change that (in your `factor` definition of Dataset) and they'll come out in a different order.